# How to correct shape misalignment when multiplying pandas dataframe with a vector for dot product?

Tags: python, pandas

My objective is to calculate the dot product of each row of the matrix (dim 11 X 12) with a vector. the matrix is imported from excel as a dataframe using read excel function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import array, dot, random

weights=np.array([62.3835,9.9098,-35.424,32.406,-99.9,143.57,-27.888,57.0654,10.4995,175.115,138.24,-0.8514])

b=weights.reshape(1,12)

set1rl = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\largetest.xlsx",       sheetname='set1',header=0,index_col=0,parse_cols = "B:M", skip_footer=42)
set1rl.as_matrix()
```

---

```
np.shape(b)
Out[27]: (1L, 12L)

set1rl.shape
Out[28]: (11, 11)

print set1rl
271  18.1  59  13  -154  1  1.1  54  28  0  1.2
18                                                 
19  305    19  62  13  -145  2    1  57  21  1    1
18  271    18  59  13  -154  1    1  54  28  0    1
16  234    17  54  12  -133  2    1  65  18  3    1
17  228    17  54  13  -142  1    1  65  27  0    1
16  220    16  53  13  -159  1    1  57  35  0    1
20  324    20  65  13  -137  3    1  61  18  1    1
16  151    12  48  15   -62  2    2  99 -18  7    1
16  227    17  53  13  -149  1    1  64  33  0    1
18  266    18  57  12  -152  1    1  57  28  0    1
18  256    17  57  13  -152  1    1  57  28  0    1
19  302    19  62  13  -150  1    1  57  27  0    1
```

I get the following error.

```
ValueError: shapes (1,12) and (11,11) not aligned: 12 (dim 1) != 11 (dim 0)
```

The pandas counting seems to be zero indexed while the vector values are not. How do I then calculate the dot product?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you show the shape of `set1rl` as `11 x 11` not `11 x 12`.  That's the problem.  Nothing to do with zero indexing.  I think you meant to import your excel file without an index but instead you told it that your index is at column `0` when you passed `index_col=0`.  To parse without an index (and have pandas create one for you), you don't have to do anything, that's the default behavior.  Delete the `index_col=0` parameter from your `read_excel` call.